# Selecting individual calendars using check boxes or radio buttons for FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to create a calendar that shows multiple calendar feeds from google. In addition to this I am looking to added a feature that allows the user to select the calendars he/she views using either check boxes or radio buttons.

The code that brings in the calendars from google is as follows, I am new to JavaScript and in the process of learning using Lynda.com.

```
eventSources: [
                {
                url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/australian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
                color: 'red',
                },
                {
                url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/indian__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
                color: 'green',
                },
                {
                url: "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/vietnamese__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic",
                color: 'yellow',
                },
            ],
```

Can anyone help me with the html and javascript needed to choose these calendars individually using check boxes or radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the ["events as a function"](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/). In that function, check if the boxes are checked using simple jQuery and if they are, just add those events to an array along with the others and send the array to callback.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I currently used a conditional statement which goes through the radio buttons and selects the feed based on an onclick value. Your solution seems to be cleaner. I will give it a go this week thanks for pointing it out.